# jQuery / JavaScript test for email && checkbox validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I test for form validation for both variables: emailAddr && items[].

items[] is a checkbox array.

Currently the code below won't submit the form at all.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var re = /(\w+)\@(\w+)\.[a-zA-Z]/g;
        var email = document.getElementById("emailAddr");
        var emailValue = email.value;
        var testEmail = re.test(emailValue);
        jQuery("#submitForm").on("click",function(){
            if (jQuery("input[name*='items']").is(":checked"), 
                testEmail === true){
                return true;
            } else {
              jQuery('#messages').append("You must choose at least 1 image<br>
                                         Please enter a valid email");
              return false;
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: Put your email check code inside your `on("click"...` handler.

Comment: Yes, that made all the difference, now the form submits, but without checking the checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleaning up the code a little to check for the value on submission may help but I do not know exactly how the html is formatted to see why else the form may not be submitting.

```
var re = /(\w+)\@(\w+)\.[a-zA-Z]/g;
var email = document.getElementById("emailAddr");
jQuery("#submitForm").on("click",function(e){
     var emailValue = email.value;
     var testEmail = re.test(emailValue);
     if (jQuery("input[name*='items']").is(":checked") && testEmail === true){
         return true;
     } else {
         e.preventDefault(); // prevents the form from submitting if invalid
         jQuery('#messages').append("You must choose at least 1 image<br>Please enter a valid email");
         return false;
     }
});
```

Comment: Yes that made a difference, but now the form submits without the items[] being validated...

Comment: Updated my code to accommodate what I believe is happening

Comment: Thanks, it's rudimentary stuff... :) Working perfectly now

Comment: Glad I could help!